# Método para comprobar si una tabla esta vacia

Tags: android, sqlite, if

¿Alguien podría decirme como puedo verificar si una tabla de la bd de mi app esta vacía?

Mi idea es llamar a un método dentro de un if y que compruebe si esta vacía o no y me devuelva un tipo de dato booleano.

```
if(checkDataBaseInf("cartera")==true){
  //Si existen datos perfecto
}
else{
  //Si no existen datos tareas a realizar.....
}

public boolean checkDataBase(String Database_path){
  //Ha esta parte me refiero con mi consulta del post
}
```

Clase que se encarga de la creación de la tabla:

```
public class CarteraSQLiteOpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {


public CarteraSQLiteOpenHelper(Context context, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version) {
    super(context, name, factory, version);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    //Se ejecuta las sentencias SQL de creación de las tablas
    String query = "CREATE TABLE CARTERA (id_cartera INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, saldo INTEGER);";
    db.execSQL(query);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    //En caso de cambio de version se ejecutaria esta bloque de codigo
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS CARTERA;");
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE CARTERA (id_cartera INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, saldo INTEGER);");
}

//Metodo que me permite abrir la tabla
public void abrirBDCartera() {
    this.getWritableDatabase();
}

//Metodo que me permite cerrar la tabla
public void cerrarBDCartera() {
    this.close();
}

//Metodo que me permite realizar insert en la tabla
public void insertarCartera(int saldo) {
    ContentValues valores = new ContentValues();
    valores.put("saldo", saldo);
    this.getWritableDatabase().insert("cartera", null, valores);
}

//Metodo que me permite realizar update en la tabla
public void modificarCartera(int saldo) {
    ContentValues valores = new ContentValues();
    valores.put("saldo", saldo);
    this.getWritableDatabase().update("cartera", valores, "id_cartera = ?", new String[]{"1"});
}
}
```

Hasta el momento he realizado esto:

```
    private boolean checkDataBaseInf(String Database_path){
    SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;
    int count = 0;

    try {
        checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(Database_path, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
        Cursor cursor = checkDB.rawQuery("SELECT count(*) FROM " + Database_path, null);

        try {
            if (cursor != null)
                if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {
                    cursor.moveToFirst();
                    count = cursor.getInt(0);
                }
        } finally {
            if (cursor != null && !cursor.isClosed()) {
                cursor.close();
            }
        }

    } catch (SQLiteException e){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "NO BD2", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return false;
    }

    if(count>0) {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

¿Podria gestionarlo así?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para comprobar si la tabla está vacía te sobraría con hacer una consulta para ver cuantos elementos tiene esa tabla.

A continuación te dejaré un ejemplo de consulta:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM tabla
```

Y un ejemplo de función:

```
public boolean checkEmpty(String tabla){
    int count = 0;
    CarteraSQLiteOpenHelper mDbHelper = new CarteraSQLiteOpenHelper(getContext());

    SQLiteDatabase db = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT count(*) FROM " + tabla, null);

    try {
        if(cursor != null)
            if(cursor.getCount() > 0){
                cursor.moveToFirst();
                count = cursor.getInt(0);
            }
    }finally {
        if (cursor != null && !cursor.isClosed()) {
            cursor.close();
        }
    }

    if(count>0)
       return false;
    else
       return true;
}
```

Otra alternativa sería la de utilizar la función [queryNumEntries](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/DatabaseUtils.html#queryNumEntries%28android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase,%20java.lang.String%29) de la clase [DatabaseUtils](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/DatabaseUtils.html) de la siguiente forma:

```
public boolean checkEmpty(SQLiteDatabase db, String tabla){
        return DatabaseUtils.queryNumEntries(db, tabla) == 0;
}
```

**EDIT:** échale un ojo a la documentación de Android sobre [cómo guardar datos en BD](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html?hl=es) o a este otro [manual](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidSQLite/article.html) en el que te ponen ejemplos de cómo manejar las BD

Comment: Vale con la actualizacion que has hecho he comprendido mejor el tema de la sobrecarga. Mucha gracias ;D

Comment: no había visto bien tu clase, ahora editare la función acorde lo que tienes, bastaría con eliminar ese parámetro y poner this.getWritableDatabase().rawquery , lo había puesto así porque no sabia como obtenías la bd

Comment: buuf estoy teniendo problemas, tanto si sobrecargo el método con un SQLiteDatabase o si no ya que no se como referenciar ese objeto. Me refiero a que esto voy a implementarlo en un splash scrren. Primero entra por un if y verifica si existe la tabla y despues deberia de hacer esto... voy a abrir un nuvo hilo done lo explicare mejor

Comment: He añadido lo que tengo hasta ahora al final de la consulta a ver que te parece. ¿Puedo sacar una SQLiteDataBase de esa forma? Este método lo utilizare cuatro veces una por cada tabla, entonecs pasandole el nombre de la base de datos en la llamada del método me serviria? ¿Seria un método dinamico capaz de comprobar distintas tablas? Gracias de antemano @Joacer

Comment: Acabo de modificar la respuesta, échale un ojo a los enlaces que te he puesto en los que tienes ejemplos de cómo manejar BD, en teoría el método que te he suministrado es dinámico, ya que por parámetro le pasas el nombre de la tabla que quieres comprobar

Comment: Bien lo probaré ahora. Lo único que yo me estoy dando cuenta que hice mal el planteamiento de las clases que extienden de SQLOpenHelper ya que cree una clase por cada una de las cuatro tablas que tiene mi app. Ya que en la solución que acabas de actualizar instancias CarteraSQLiteHelper solo podría realizar la verificación de esa tabla (siempre y cuando coincida con el parámetro que sobrecargo con el nombre de la tabla). En cambio si quisiera hacer la comprobación de otra tabla debería instanciar las otras tres clases que tengo extendidas de SQLOpenHelper. Voy bien encaminado? @Joacer

Comment: Aunque podría instanciar las cuatro clases:**CarteraSQLiteOpenHelper mDbHelper = new CarteraSQLiteOpenHelper(getContext()); ValorSQLiteOpenHelper mDbHelper = new ValorSQLiteOpenHelper(getContext()); EstadoSQLiteOpenHelper mDbHelper = new EstadoSQLiteOpenHelper(getContext()); HistorialSQLiteOpenHelper mDbHelper = new HistorialSQLiteOpenHelper(getContext());** hacer un switch dentro del método y a la hora de hacer la llamada desde fuera pasarle como parámetros el nombre de la tabla y un número y en caso de ser uno u otro quedarme con una instancia o otra?? Es elegante o quedará chapuzero?

Comment: @EduardoMéndez yo de normal lo que hago es tener una clase que hereda SQLiteOpenHelper en la que creo  la BD y todas sus tablas, y después me creo otras clases para cada tabla en las que hago las operaciones sobre las tablas, y para abrir la BD hago lo que te he puesto yluego cierro la BD

Comment: Switch Case1:CarteraSQLiteOpenHelper mDbHelper = new CarteraSQLiteOpenHelper(getContext()); Case2:ValorSQLiteOpenHelper mDbHelper = new ValorSQLiteOpenHelper(getContext()); etc etc

Comment: Comprendo es la primera vez que toco bd en Android y de ahí me error veré como gestionó el tema sin toquetear mucho el código. Gracias figura 

Comment: @EduardoMéndez intenta ver algún ejemplo completo de BD de como se estructura y como se interactua e intenta crearte un ejemplo tu fuera de tu proyecto con la BD y las tablas que quieras crear, una vez consigas hacerlo funcionar integralo en tu proyecto, creo que de esta forma te resultará más fácil comprender cómo utilizar las BD